# Ionic ng-click navigate to state removes menu on left

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following menu template
The below `<ion-side-menus>` lives in `template/menu/menu.html`

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>        
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>    

    <ion-side-menu enable-menu-with-back-views="true" side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <div ui-view="leftMenuContent"></div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

When navigating from a html file using the following technique

```
<ion-view view-title="Nutrition">
    <ion-content class="padding">
     <button class="button button-full button-calm" ng-click="viewPlans()">Plans
     </button>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>

home.controller('NutritionController', function ($state) {

    $scope.viewPlans = function () {
      $state.go('app.home.nutrition.plan');
    };
});
```

The `<ion-side-menus>` gets completely removed and replaced with the content that was loaded from the state i.e just one screen without menus on the left.

Navigating from a html file using the following technique

```
<ion-view view-title="Nutrition">
    <ion-content class="padding">
       <a ui-sref="app.home.nutrition.plan" class="button button-full button-calm" menu-close>Plans</a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The menu on the left stays there only closes and the content gets loaded into the content part of the menu.

Below is my routes:

```
.state('app', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'template/menu/menu.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl as mainCtrl'
})
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'menuContent@app': {
            templateUrl: 'template/home.html',
            controller: "HomeController as homeCtrl"
        },
        'leftMenuContent@app': {
            templateUrl: 'template/menu/left/main.html',
            controller: "HomeController as homeCtrl"
        }
    }
})
.state('app.home.nutrition', {
    url: '/nutrition',
    views: {
        'menuContent@app': {
            templateUrl: 'template/nutrition.html',
            controller: "NutritionController as nutritionCtrl"
        },
        'leftMenuContent@app': {
            templateUrl: 'template/menu/left/nutritionMenu.html'
        }
    }
})
    .state('app.home.nutrition.plan', {
        url: '/plan',
        views: {
            'menuContent@app': {
                templateUrl: 'template/plan/plan.html',
                controller: "PlanController as planCtrl"
            },
            'leftMenuContent@app': {
                templateUrl: 'template/menu/left/planMenu.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a way that I can keep the menu on the left when doing a ng-click?

Comment: You have probably messed up the combination of routes declarations + ion-view in the html. Show us your routes

Comment: I did a edit on the post, please see the routes.

Comment: You have menuContent and leftMenuContent and in every state you are replacing the view. app.home.nutrition.plan for example replaces both menucontent and leftMenuContent. Btw, where are you loading your actual content?

Comment: The actual main content gets loaded in the menuContent, i.e. this is like a main page which holds info. The leftMenuContent holds the dynamic menu links, which gets loaded when a state loads i.e. Home etc.. links. When the specific state loads, it loads its main content into the menuContent via menuContent@app and its left menu links via leftMenuContent@app.

Comment: But the menuContent view seems to be inside the menu. So you are loading your content inside a menu (?)

Comment: Should the content be loaded outside the <ion-side-menus>? From my understanding, the menu which is <ion-side-menus> holds the menu links on the left or right and then the content you wish to load in the <ion-nav-view>

Comment: I just checked an app of my own, you are right about the markup.